# Azure Data Factory v2 U-SQL Script Cannot find secret information for credential

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I'm facing an issue when running a U-SQL Script with Azure Data Factory V2.
Script use external data source - Azure SQL DB:

```
@azuresqldb =
    SELECT Convert.ToInt32(user_id) AS user_id
    FROM EXTERNAL BIAzureSQLDBDataSource LOCATION "dbo.myTable";
```

And it works properly when I run script directly in DLA. But when ADF execute 
script it fail with error:

> {
>       "errorCode": "2703",
>       "message": "Error Id: E_CSC_USER_CREDENTIALSECRETNOTFOUND, Error Message: Cannot find secret information for credential 'AmplitudeDB.BIAzureSQLDBCredential'}

Scripts without external data sources working fine. My ADF account has contributor role in Data Lake Analytics. 
How I can fix this?

Comment: I noticed that the script works in the default database [master]